# How to handle major changes (cross-cutting concerns) in REST API?

Tags: architecture, rest, versioning, integration

Let's say we have a REST API application A consumed by other 30 applications. Application "A" uses a cross-cutting security implementation using a Security NuGet package 1.0. All minor/major changes are properly versioned and backwards compatible (e.g. not breaking existing consumers with new changes).

The problem is, what happens if you need to upgrade your Security NuGet package to 2.0 and do major changes to your security across application A. 
Technically, the API contract between source and consumers don't change but you may need a thorough regression testing to make sure app A with Security 2.0 is not breaking any existing functionality in any of the 30 consumers

Should you:

1. Create a new source code base for Security 2.0 version of the app and Deploy and maintain old and new versions of the app? Then move the 30 consumers gradually to the new API? or
2. Migrate app A to Security 2.0 and do thorough regression testing from all 30 consumers

What is the recommended approach to handle these type of changes that span across applications and cannot be handled through endpoint versioning? E.g. wide cross-cutting security implementation? In theory your source API (app A) should be agnostic of consumers as long as it's not breaking them).

As this article points out, this is not a versioning problem but a change management problem: https://www.ben-morris.com/rest-apis-dont-need-a-versioning-strategy-they-need-a-change-strategy/

Comment: Which approach provide the best balance of benefits, risks and costs?

Comment: Having been at a company that never forced clients to upgrade, and just kept making new versions of an application, I can tell you it is a maintenance nightmare.  I would recommend 2.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1 is really a waste of time. You are essentially proposing to launch a new service that has no consumers yet and is very similar to identical to an existing service. There is no incentive in here for the 30 existing consumers (or even for new consumers) to use that new service.

I get the feeling that you see option 2 as a big-bang transition: A big effort is put in testing all 30 consumers and when that is ok, the productions servers go from A-with-Security1.0 to A-with-Security2.0 all at once.

My preferred approach would be something like a middle ground between those two.

Suppose you are currently running software version 10.0 of A, which uses Security 1.0. You negotiate a transition period for the 30 consumers during which version 10.0 of A will remain available, but not get any updates except critical security fixes.
Then you start updating A to use Security 2.0 and you release version 11.0 of A. This new version gets deployed *in parallel to* the existing version 10.0. At this point, the transition period for the consumers officially starts.
Next, the consumer applications are transitioned *one by one* to use the new version of A and tested to verify there are no interoperability issues. It is recommended to start with the applications that are most likely to uncover problems due to the change from Security 1.0 to Security 2.0 to reduce the retesting effort when problems are found.

Comment: `At this point, the transition period for the consumers officially starts.` Also starts for new consumers. New consumers should not be allowed to consume the older version. Basically, we strangle the old version until it dies because it has no traffic.